# rails server not starting- undefined method `formatter' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using rails 4.1, but when i try to run 'rails s' on the terminal it give this error:

```
Exiting
/home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@addtocartalerts/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start': undefined method `formatter' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@addtocartalerts/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@addtocartalerts/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@addtocartalerts/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

please help

Comment: its like the gemset was changed by an IDE that I was trying out, I fixed it thanks you all

Answer (score 1):

You are not using rails 4.1. Look at the railties gem path. It says railties 4.0.4

Check Gemfile for right version. Do `bundle update rails`. Then use binstubs or `bundle exec rails s` if you have multiple rails gems installed